# C#. Нужен ли делегат если данные COM порта не для вывода в UI а для обработки в программе?

Tags: c#, serial, port, делегаты

Как увидеть **indata** снаружи DataReceivedHandler? Все что находил в интернете решало проблему вывода в textbox с использованием делегата, но мне не нужен вывод в UI а просто вытащить переменную строкового типа обработать ее и отправить в Modbus TCP.

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();


    }
```

Comment: DataReceivedHandler выполняется в дополнительном потоке, так что при необходимости доступа к общим данным нужно использовать какие-либо средства синхронизации. Нет обращения к общим данным из разных потоков - нет и нужды в синхронизации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`вытащить переменную строкового типа обработать ее и отправить в Modbus TCP`

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

    ProcessIndata(indata);
    SendToModbus(indata);
}
```

вам осталось реализовать `ProcessIndata` и `SendToModbus`

Comment: спасибо, все заработало!

Comment: @TYTAHXAMOH пожалуйста